# Quick question on using SVD for data compression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

[Here](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-svd), in paragraph *Data compression*, one can find this sentence:

> This means that we have three vectors $v_i$, each of which has $15$ entries, three vectors $u_i$, each of which has $25$ entries, and three singular values $\sigma_i$. This implies that we may represent the matrix using only $123$ numbers rather than the $375$ that appear in the matrix.

Can anyone please explain where "$123$ numbers" come from? How do I get this dimension?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240127/116107).

Answer (score 1):

From the number of components in the given vectors and the number of singular values,
$3\times15+3\times25+3=123$

Comment: Thanks, can you please show how this matrix would look? Is there any rule for that?

Comment: Upon expansion of the products of the vectors, M has been written as the sum of three matrices, each with the same dimension as M. For further discussion of SVD look at the example in the above comments and the links therein.